# How to do a silent refresh via implicit flow in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, oauth-2.0, token

so I have the problem that our token won't refresh. More than that, our entire website is getting duplicated. Here's the background:

We have the following auth config (more or less):

```
export const authConfig: AuthConfig = {
    issuer: '[censored]',
    redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/',
    silentRefreshRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/assets/login-sources/silent-refresh.html',
    tokenEndpoint: '[censored]',
    loginUrl: '[same as tokenEndpoint]',
    clientId: '[censored]',
    scope: '[censored]',
    clearHashAfterLogin: true,
    oidc: true,
};
```

And we also have a loginService, which does roughly the following onInit:

```
this.oauthService.configure(authConfig);
this.oauthService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler();
// this.oauthService.setupAutomaticSilentRefresh(); - didn't work
this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument([censored]).then((doc) => {
  // Subscribe to expiration event to refresh token.
  this.oauthService.events
    .pipe(filter(element => element.type === 'token_expires'))
    .subscribe(
      (a) => {
        console.log("Token is about to expire! Refreshing!");
        this.oauthService.silentRefresh().then(result => console.log(result)).catch(error => console.error(error));
      }
    );
  if (this.userid == null) {
    this.oauthService.tryLoginImplicitFlow().then((loggedIn) => {
      if (!loggedIn) {
        this.oauthService.initLoginFlow();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The problem: whenever the token expired, the following things happen:

- The entire website clones its instance so two instances are running in parallel (according to console)
  => this is even worse if we use automaticSilentRefresh without all those event listeners. There, it clones itself indefinitely until it runs out of RAM
- A few seconds later we get a "refresh timeout" error in the console, without a stack trace.

So I looked into the code of silentRefresh() and it seems it works with an iframe. In said iframe SHOULD be just simple code that is used to refresh the token and "communicate to the main application" [see here. We even implemented the refresh.html like here](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/blob/master/docs-src/silent-refresh.md). In our case however, we have an iframe where the entire website is mirrored. This means we have something like this:

```
html
  head /head
  body
    app-root /app-root
    iframe
      app-root /app-root
    /iframe
  /body
/html
```

Since for every silentRefresh(), the iframe gets removed and re-added into the DOM, each time a new instance of the whole website is created. What did I do wrong and how can I fix this?

Versions:
Angular 9 +
"angular-oauth2-oidc": "^9.0.1",
"angular-oauth2-oidc-jwks": "^9.0.0".

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this, which I use for some samples of mine, is to only render the main app when running on the main window. In my small sample I use index.html for both the main app and the renewal iframe, but vary the code that runs.

Mine is a [ReactJS Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/index.tsx) and this is the technique I have used. Hopefully this helps in a manner that isn't too intrusive, though there may be alternative solutions.

```
if (window.top === window.self) {

    // Run the main ReactJS app
    render (
        <App />,
        document.getElementById('root'),
    );
} else {

    // Run a minimal app to handle the iframe renewal
    const app = new IFrameApp();
    app.execute();
}
```

Comment: Sadly your approach doesn't translate well to this Angular plugin. To me it seems like implicit flow is just broken. We just switched to code flow today and now it runs perfectly. ^^

Comment: Cool - you should be using Authorization Code Flow (PKCE) these days, since implicit flow is deprecated for SPAs - glad you have resolved your problem ..